# Get element by ALT

Tags: javascript, jquery, powershell

I would like to make an autologin script (for my company, each employee works on 3 computers and has to login on 15 different sites and apps - so i need a autologin) 
powershell

```
$Url = “www.gmail.com”


$Username=”xxxxxxx”

$Password=”xxxxxxxx”


$Executable = "c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe"

$IE = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application;
$IE.visible = $true;
$IE.navigate($url);


while ($IE.Busy -eq $true)

{

Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 2000;

}


$IE.Document.getElementById(“login_nickname”).value = $Username
$IE.Document.getElementByID(“login_passwort”).value=$Password



$IE.Document.getElementbyID("login").Click();
console.log($img.alt);

while ($IE.Busy -eq $true)

{

Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 2000;

}

Invoke-Item $Executable
```

So, I have login and password entered correctly, but I am not able to click login button - it doesnt have an ID. Only alt value. And the button is a hyperlink. It doesnt work if i use getElementByID and enter alt value which is LOGIN but it doesnt work (below)

```
$IE.Document.getElementbyID("login").Click();
```

Comment: Can you share the DOM structure!, The `HTML` of the form that you play with.

Comment: That line

<input type="image" src="/img/inf-btn-login.gif" alt="Login">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter it by the button text?

```
$IE.Document.links | ? {$_.TextContent -eq "login"}
```

Use it like this:

```
($IE.Document.links | ? {$_.TextContent -eq "login"} | Select -First 1).Click
```

Comment: So

> $IE.Document.links | ? TextContent -eq "login" 

and now 

    Click()

Comment: Where-Object Cannot bind parameter FilterScript. Cannot convert the Textcontent value of type System.String to type System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.

Comment: @MarcinFrankowski try the version there now? I was using the PSv5 syntax.

Comment: No errors, but it doesnt work anyway. site is big7 dot com :D